What is the best way to learn applied dynamic programming?
I want to learn dynamic programming in a more applied fashion. I want to be able to solve problems of the likes of Recursive Macroeconomic Theory. I want to be able to solve problems using pen and paper and a computer.

Please be more specific with your question so that potential answers can be more focused. Perhaps you can try out some problems from Ljungqvist and Sargent and come back to this site with questions about specific steps where you're stuck.

A good start for beginners may be Chapter 4 of The ABCs of RBCs by George McCandless. It has an example both analytically and with code.

@jpfeifer Thank you for your answer I will check this out. Herr K. my question is rather general. I want to know your recommendation on what would be a good intro on dynamic programming so I can be able to go through Recursive Macroeconomic Theory book.
